# Checking Numerical Precision in Algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, numerical

what is the best practice to check for numerical precision in algorithms?
Is there any suggested technique to resolve the problem "how do we know the result we calculated is correct"?
If possible: are there some example of numerical precision enhancement in C++?

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: int types = 100% precision on supported interval of Integer numbers. float types = support only for a fraction of Rational numbers. Arbitrary precision for rational numbers (that you can choose from) is achieved through various libraries that store these as 2 integers, sometimes called "Decimals" or "Fractional numbers"

Comment: @deathApril - `3/2 == 1` is **not** 100% precision. It's just that it's what programmers have learned to expect. Unfortunately, they typically haven't learned enough about floating-point to know what to expect from expressions like `3.333 * 3.0`.

Comment: @PeteBecker `3/2 == 1` for [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), remainder is 1.

Comment: @deathApril - yes, obviously. And whatever "anomalies" you see in floating-point arithmetic are **correct** for floating-point arithmetic. As I said, most programmers just don't know enough about floating-point arithmetic to get it right.

Comment: @deathApril: `3/2==1` because of the limited number of bits, in particular 0 bits for the fractional part. Floating point has a variable number of bits for the fractional part (that's why it's not _fixed_ point), but even that variable number is still limited.

Comment: no one learns integer arithmetic in the high schools anymore or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Math::BigFloat](http://search.cpan.org/~pjacklam/Math-BigInt-1.997/lib/Math/BigFloat.pm) / [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/~pjacklam/Math-BigInt-1.997/lib/Math/BigInt.pm) will help. I must say there are many libraries that do this, I don't know which would be best. Maybe someone else has a nice answer for you.

In general though, you can write it twice: once with unlimited precision, and one without then verify the two. That's what I do with the scientific software I write. Then I'll write a third that does fancier speed enhancements. This way I can verify all three. Mind you, I know the three won't be exactly equal, but they should have enough significant figures of corroboration.

To actually *know* how much error is difficult to obtain accurately --remember order of operations of floating point numbers can cause large differences. It's really problem specific but if you know the relative magnitude of certain numbers you can change the order of operations to get accuracy (multiply a list in sorted order for example). Two places to look for investigating this is,

- Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic
- [What Every Computer Scientist needs to know about Floating Point Arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [Anatomy of a Floating Point Number](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/06/anatomy-of-a-floating-point-number/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at interval arithmetic, for example

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm

It will produce upper and lower bounds on results

PS: also have a look at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html